# Group policy file access via wildcards

Tags: windows, file-permissions, group-policy, wildcards

We have a scanning folder for every user on our NAS, this scan folder is used by our copy machine which "connects as the user" to the NAS and uploads the file there. We have started to change user passwords regulary and that would mean that we need to change the credentials on the copy machine every time the user changes them. So we decided to create a separate user that would have read/write access only to their scan folder.

The folder patch is always as this \nas\users\"Username"\_SCAN and all the scanned files go to the _SCAN folder.

Is there an easy way to asign read/write permissions only to the _SCAN folder of each user and only read on the path before? For example via group policy?

\nas\users"Username" - Read
_SCAN - Read/Write

So that everytime we add a new user we don't have to assign the permissions?

I have tried to use the basic wildcars like * ** when setting GP this way - “Computer Configuration” ➔ “Policies” ➔ “Windows Settings” ➔ “Security Settings” ➔ “File System”. But it requires a specific folder.

I could always just set it on the whole folder users, but for some security measure I would like it just on the _SCAN folder.

I will be glad for any advice on this matter.
Thank you

Comment: You need to do some scripting for that. And you will need to use iCACLS utility for that https://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html or Powershell script and Set-ACL command. You need to iterate through each scan folder path in batch.

Comment: @Hardoman Oh, that makes sense. I will try that. Thank you.

Comment: Feel free to upvote if it helped you.